# Casting void** and setting first byte to nullptr?

Tags: c++, casting

In a chunk allocator I just came across the pattern. It was probably written to work in C, but I'm working in C++17.

```
...

void * chunk = malloc(size);
((void**)chunk)[0] = NULL; // ???
if (last_chunk != NULL) {
  ((void**)last_chunk)[0] = chunk;
else {
  first_chunk = chunk;
}
```

Why would you cast to `void**` and set the first byte to `NULL` in this case? <strike>And can I instead just do `chunk = NULL`, without the cast, as `operator[]` just dereferences the `void**` to a `void*` anyway?</strike> (/edit: do not do chunk = NULL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chunk = NULL` would set the pointer you've just allocated to NULL.

`*chunk = NULL` is invalid, you can't dereference a void pointer.

`((void**)chunk)` casts the pointer to an array of pointers and `((void**)chunk)[0] = NULL` sets the first element of that array to `NULL` (or the first sizeof(void*) bytes of the allocated memory to 0).

`memset(chunk, 0, sizeof(void*))` would be an alternative way of achieving the same result.

Comment: Suggestion: "`chunk = NULL` would set the pointer to the memory you've just allocated to NULL, leaking it`"

Comment: `((void**)chunk)` causes the pointer to a pointer-to-pointer. Not to an array. You cannot cast to arrays.

Comment: Also the code writes a null pointer which is not necessarily all-bits-zero, although usually is on common platforms. Accordingly the `memset` suggestion is not equivalent, in portable code

Comment: As M.M said, an constant integral expression evaluating to zero converts to a NULL pointer, but the post-`memset` value is not a constant integral expression.